# Error forge iOS package

Tags: trigger.io

When I try to forge a package with trigger.io,  I get the following error :

[ERROR] Failed when running /usr/bin/codesign: /Dropbox/WWW/TriggerDev/development/ios/device-ios.app: replacing invalid existing signature
/Dropbox/WWW/TriggerDev/development/ios/device-ios.app: object file format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable

Could you help me fix this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error normally means that your iOS developer environment is not set up correctly: is your developer certificate allowed to use the provisioning profile you've specified?

Also, if you're using our Parse push notification integration, you'll need to enable push notifications for your app, as described in their docs: https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#push

**NOTE** it seems that not having the Xcode command line tools installed can cause this problem too - see comment from @MyWetSocks. Go to Preferences > Downloads.

Comment: Command line tool of Xcode wasn't installed (go to Preference to install it) Now it runs perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! :) Had this problem just now. Feel a bit stupid really! haha